# Escaping double quotes in Firebird

Tags: escaping, firebird, firebird2.5

I have the following SQL statement:

```
  FOR
    SELECT A.BLIEF_MASKENKEY,
    A.BLIEF_BADR_NAME,
    A.BSA_MASKENKEY,
    A.BLLC_MASKENKEY,
    A.LLTERMIN,
    A.BLLC_ERFASSUNGSDATUM,
    A.WE_MENGE,
    A.BBESP_BESTMENGE,
    A.BBESP_ARTKZ,
    B.BREKL_MASKENKEY,
    B.MASKENKEY,
    B.BREKL_BLIEF_MASKENKEY,
    B.BLIEF_BADR_NAME,
    B.BSA_MASKENKEY,
    B.BSA_ARTBEZ,
    B.MENGE,
    B.ERFASST_AM,
    B.FERTIG_BIS,
    B.BREKLPOVERURS_MASKENKEY,
    B.BREKLPOVERURS_BEZ,
    B.BREKLFEHLURS_MASKENKEY,
    B.BREKLFEHLURS_BEZ,
    B.BREKLFEHLART_MASKENKEY,
    B.BREKLFEHLART_BEZ,
    B.BREKLPOGARANTIE_MASKENKEY,
    B.BREKLPOGARANTIE_BEZ
FROM V_BLLCP A
LEFT OUTER JOIN V_BREKLPO B ON B.BREKL_BLIEF_ID = A.BLIEF_ID AND B.BSA_ID = A.BSA_ID_ARTNR AND B.ERFASST_AM BETWEEN :ANFANGSDATUM AND :ENDDATUM
WHERE A.LLTERMIN BETWEEN :ANFANGSDATUM AND :ENDDATUM AND
        A.BBESP_ARTKZ = '9100'
ORDER BY A.BLIEF_MASKENKEY ASC
INTO :BLIEF_MASKENKEY,
    :BLIEF_BADR_NAME,
    :BSA_MASKENKEY,
    :BLLC_MASKENKEY,
    :LLTERMIN,
    :BLLC_ERFASSUNGSDATUM,
    :WE_MENGE,
    :BBESP_BESTMENGE,

    :NUMMER,
    :LFDNR,
    :BLIEF_NR,
    :BLIEF_NAME,
    :KENNZ,
    :ARTNR,
    :ARTBEZ,
    :MENGE,
    :ERFASST_AM,
    :FERTIG_BIS,
    :VERURSACHER_CODE,
    :VERURSACHER,
    :FEHLER_CODE,
    :FEHLER,
    :FEHLERART_CODE,
    :FEHLERART,
    :RESULTAT_CODE,
    :RESULTAT
 DO
  BEGIN
    -- Relevanzfaktor bestimmen
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0001') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.05;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0002') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0003') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.5;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0004') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.5;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0005') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0006') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0007') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0008') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0009') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0010') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0011') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0012') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0013') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0014') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0.1;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0015') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0;
    IF (RESULTAT_CODE = 'L0016') THEN RELEVANZ_DEZ = 0;

    RELEVANZ = RELEVANZ_DEZ * 100;
    RELEVANZ = CAST(RELEVANZ AS INTEGER);
    RELEVANZ = CAST(RELEVANZ || '%' AS VARCHAR(10));
    RELEVANZ_MENGE = MENGE * RELEVANZ_DEZ;


    SUSPEND;
  END
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

> Error conversion from String: "Some "string" here".

I can see that the query successfully returned 3 sets of data, however with the 4th set, the `BLIEF_BADR_NAME` field contains doubles quotes (Like "this"). I believes this is where it breaks down. How can I escape the doubles quotes, would anyone know?

At least I believe this is causing the problem.

Comment: Is your database dialect 1? Exactly what is throwing this error? What programming language are you using? Firebird itself has no error _"Error conversion from String ..."_ (or variations of that), which leads me to believe that your problem may be elsewhere (eg trying to convert a string value to a number or something similar). Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying this enough. I was not aware that the error did not occur from Firebird itself.

I'm using IBExpert 2011.06.29 and I'm trying to write a procedure which contains this query. The language being using is Delphi.
The DB is dialect 3.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (and please, focus on both **minimal** and **complete**), and include all relevant error information

Comment: Please make this clear that this `"` is single quote twice or double quote in your text. Also check by copy paste in some editor that its not Unicode String.

as using Firebird function `REPLACE (str, find, repl)` you can replace the single quote to double quote, but double quote should not cause any problem. Else remove double quotes to solve the issue

Comment: This IF sequence is fragile... imagine if `RESULTAT_CODE = 'ABC01'` or any other forgotten not represented value - then the `RELEVANZ_DEZ` variable would not get changed, would be left from prior iteration. I believe better to use single assignment statement using `DECODE` function having fallback default value.

Comment: `RELEVANZ = CAST(RELEVANZ AS INTEGER);  RELEVANZ = CAST(RELEVANZ || '%' AS VARCHAR(10));` - no, really, why on Earth??? `RELEVANZ = CAST( ROUND( RELEVANZ_DEZ * 100 ) AS VARCHAR(9) ) || '%'` See https://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc.html

Comment: `I'm using IBExpert 2011.06.29` - quite old. Does the problem happen in IBExpert or only in your Delphi code? Can you try latest build of IBExpert (trial or personal if not purchased)? This error almost surely happens outside of the firebird